# Check support for shadow dom v1 in browser using javascript

Tags: html, web-component, shadow-dom

Is there any way to check the browser under consideration have support for shadow dom v1?

What is performance hit of using it in the application?

I want to use it so that I can project the html content retrieved from server with css into my current view without disturbing existing css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [Shadow DOM v1 presentation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom#support):

> To feature detect shadow DOM, check for the existence of attachShadow:
>
> `const supportsShadowDOMV1 = !!HTMLElement.prototype.attachShadow;`

There's no performance concern unless you deal with thousands of Shadow DOM at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check in shadowDOM is **natively** supported then use this:

`const supportsShadowDom = !!/{s+[native code]s+}/.test((HTMLElement.prototype.attachShadow||'').toString());`

If you don't care if it is supported through a polyfill then use this:

`const supportsShadowDom = !!HTMLElement.prototype.attachShadow;`